# xmllint: combine find command with xmllint command

Tags: xmllint

I have a number of xml files in a directory. I can list them:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | grep "/path/to/directory/"
```

And then I can search for a value in individual file:

```
xmllint --xpath "//bundle/artifact" /path/to/directory/abc.xml
```

How can I do both steps in a single command, and eliminating duplicate results as well? I tried this, expecting output of first two commands would act as input to xmllint command, but doesn't work:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | grep "/path/to/directory/" | xmllint --xpath "//bundle/artifact"
```

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: It is /bin/bash

Comment: try `find "/path/to/directory" -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} xmllint --xpath "//bundle/artifact" {}`